# Qt 5.5 WinRT x64 VS2013 applications fail WACK Direct3D tests

Tags: qt, windows-runtime

I downloaded latest Qt 5.5 x64 WinRT VS2013 binaries, created basic QWidget application and converted my Qt project to VS project by executing "qmake -tp vc .pro "CONFIG+=windeployqt"". The VS2013 project could be compiled and launched easily but both Windows Application Certification Kit Direct3D feature tests failed. I also have tested Several Qt example projects on Win 10 VirtualBox and Win 8.1 PC with the same result. Tried all these things with Qt 5.5 WinRT x86 VS2013 which I've built from sources w/o success.

On the other hand I installed Qt's QuickForecast application from Windows Store and it passed all WACK tests. The only significant difference I noticed between both packages is d3dcompiler_qt.dll in QuickForecast package folder. This .dll is missing in Qt 5.5 x64 WinRT VS2013. There is a d3dcompiler_47.dll but when I put it into package I got another WACK fails connected to restricted APIs in d3dcompiler_47.dll.

Is there any way to enable Direct3D features support and passing WACK tests with Qt 5.5 WinRT x64 VS2013?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt 5.5. Will be fixed in Qt 5.5.1. https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/126680/